# Can i add an event handler for the many elements?

Tags: c++, event-handling, c++builder

Can i add an event handler for the many elements?

I have one function and many "Edit"s and i want to add this function as event handler to some 
"Edit"s.

(Borland C++ Builder 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same method as an event handler for as many events, as you want.

Comment: Use the `Sender` parameter to know which component is triggering the event.